# Invariant Violation: WebView has been removed from React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am trying to run a **2 years old** `react-native` project. When I run my project, it showing the error

> Invariant Violation: **`WebView`** has been removed from React Native. It
>   can now be ***installed and imported from*** ***`'react-native-webview'`*** instead
>   of ***`'react-native'`***. See
>   https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview

**and**

> Invariant Violation: Module **`AppRegistry`** is not a registered callable
>   module (calling runApplication)

but I haven't installed or used any package named **`react-native-webview`** or **`webview`**
and I have updated all `gradle` files and the dependencies in `package.json` to the *current versions*

**my package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.8.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.5",
    "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "^2.8.2",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.26.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.2.2",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'revamp_alpha_consumer'
    include ':react-native-spinkit'
    project(':react-native-spinkit').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-spinkit/android')
    include ':react-native-push-notification'
    project(':react-native-push-notification').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android')
    include ':react-native-maps'
    project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
    include ':react-native-image-picker'
    project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
    include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
    project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
    include ':react-native-firebase'
    project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
    include ':react-native-fetch-blob'
    project(':react-native-fetch-blob').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob/android')
    include ':react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box'
    project(':react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box/android')
    include ':@react-native-community_async-storage'
    project(':@react-native-community_async-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/android')
    apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

    include ':app'
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

    implementation project(':react-native-spinkit')
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28

        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0" // default: "+"
        firebaseVersion = "17.3.4" // default: "+"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import bgMessaging from './components/bgMessaging';
import Root from './Root';

// YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);
// AppRegistry.registerComponent('Alpharevamp', () => Root);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Root);
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging); // <-- Add this line
```

I have tried to run it after install the ***`'react-native-webview'`*** package and add its dependencies (no where used, only installed for check whether the error subsides). But the same error occurred.

[error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj8WR.png)
[error in mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnSBp.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[react-native-qrcode](https://github.com/cssivision/react-native-qrcode) which you are using in your `package.json` is no longer being maintained.

This library is using `WebView` which used as a part of react-native as below,

```
var {
    View,
    WebView,
    Platform
} = require('react-native');
```

but this is no longer compatible with newer versions of react-native & for newer version you need to import `WebView` as below,

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'
```

So it is better to remove `react-native-qrcode` & move to a different library such as [react-native-qrcode-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-scanner)

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.